# What's causing my gradient problems in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I'm designing a window poster for shop, I'm working on this in illustrator and I'm trying to achieve this clean red to black gradient or feathered effect shown here,

[image]

A few things are confusing me, why does this banding effect or lined appearance show up on the image, also I can't seem to get the red and black to fade together very well like they have on the bargain booze picture, I think there's a few tricks to this I could do with knowing, they don't have the red to greyish gradient I have before the black part, although I do notice they have a little arrow covering that part of the transition between the black and red.

It's a CMYK project. Here's my image:

[image]

Comment: RGB or CMYK? ----

Comment: See this question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30513/how-to-make-a-smooth-pms-gradient-transition-in-illustrator

Answer (score 3):

To fix this you need to match the CMYK channels in your black swatch with your red swatch.

In my example I'm using a red with CMYK values 0,100,100,0. Now for my black instead of using the values 0,0,0,100 change it to 0,100,100,100.

[image]

This black will print as a warm black. I would talk with your printer about their maximum ink coverage as this might be pushing it.

Comment: 0,100,100,100 skirts the ink limits of most CMYK printing.

Comment: @Scott offset sheet-fed or heatset web printing on a coated paper should be able to handle 300% or even a bit more, no?

Comment: Like I posted. "skirting" :)  An ink limit of 300 or 310-320 is absolutely possible. It varies based on print provider. In my experience 290 is more common and 300 is pushing the maximum. But again, that's just the print providers I work with.

Comment: Got it :) Been a while since I did any prepress work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm just wondering what is the reason behind matching the channels, I'm used to working in the RGB Mindset and I've never come across this before, I just thought of it as selecting two colours.

Comment: The default **CMYK** black has the values `0,0,0,100` with the `100` being black **K** color, this is actually not a black but a dark grey (and this is why you use a rich black when printing). So when Illustrator tries to render the gradient it turns grey before fading to red.

Now our matched black is a red black since we cranked up the Magenta and Yellow values, thus it renders smoothly from red to black.

To not get confused about what black you're using make sure Illustrator is set to display all blacks accurately in the preferences.

Comment: ^ add that comment to your answer for bonus points  (^_-)

Comment: I use this method all the time. If you think about it in terms of separations, it is effectively adding a black gradient over the top of a solid fill of the main color, since it is just grading from red to red+black.

Answer (score 1):

Try layering the black gradient over a red background (or vice versa) instead of trying to do a red-to-black gradient on a single layer:

On your top layer, create a gradient where black (or red) is at 100% opacity on one end of the color slider and white is at 0% opacity on the other end of the slider.

On the layer below color with solid red (or black).

This should allow you more control over the size of the gradient and help with the "banding effect or lined appearance" you're referring to.

Comment: This is a pretty handy method. Also allows you to use an image in your gradient (like textures) rather than just color. The downside is the difficulty (for you and the printer) of controlling the actual CMYK values across the transition.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a smooth gradient u should do this.
Make a color black rectangle and use it as the background.
Make the same size rectangle and place it on top of the black you just made.
Create a gradient for the top rectangle following the colors below.

1st color 
100 magenta - 100 yellow: 100% opacity

2nd color
100 magenta - 100 yellow - 70 black: 100% opacity

3rd color
black: 0% opacity

Then adjust the positions of the colors as you desire.

The pic below shows the result you should have.

[image]

Comment: I see a lot of banding in that sample image.

Comment: More bands then woodstock

Answer (score 0):

You could set a black rectangle underneath, then bring in a 1 bit tiff halftone and color it black. The dots would / could be whatever size you choose and you might like to experiment with larger ones.

You could also auto-trace the dots, expand them and delete the white's after un-grouping in order to have a vector shape that you could colorize with your pallette.

I like the 1 bit halftones for their ability to colorize in illustrator from the AI pallette. This would allow you to use a 100 percent k background. I however prefer to use a "darker black" in my CMYK designs for large format printing that is made of 84,73,73,91. It comes out more black than flat dark grey on a Mimake.

Comment: Hello, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!