# Illustrator: How to make color-to-transparency gradient on dark background appear without gray area

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I tried to create fade to transparency gradient. It looks fine on white background. However, on black background, there is slightly desaturated gray area between 100% opaque and 100% transparent stop (both of them are of the same color). How do I get rid of it? Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a CMYK document?

Comment: Related: [How to make a smooth PMS gradient transition in Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/30513/8708)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change the OPPOSITE color to red, or Black that will help you to get rid of desaturated gray color.

Here's is the description
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried black with no effect. However, I have already discovered the problem: I was in CMYK color mode. After I switched to RGB, everything worked fine. Anyway, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by CMYK color mode. After switching to RGB, the grayish tint disappears.